# Results from AsyncTask not getting posted to a TextView of Activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, textview

So I was trying to retrieve all the posts from the REST API I made to be outputted to a textview in my `Posts` activity. I can successfully retrieve the JSON Objects and store them in their corresponding ArrayLists. However, whenever I call my `ListPosts` function from my `Posts` activity within the AsyncTask's `onPostExecute`, its saying that my `postsSect` textview is null.

I am thinking that for some reason the `R.id` is not getting contacted, even though I declared it in `onCreate` of my `Posts`. Because of this I'm getting this error message in my logcat:

```
01-14 21:43:57.022 16588-16588/com.example.android.androidcraftsappprototype E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.androidcraftsappprototype, PID: 16588
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
        at com.example.android.androidcraftsappprototype.WSAdapter$SendPostsRequest.onPostExecute(WSAdapter.java:186)
        at com.example.android.androidcraftsappprototype.WSAdapter$SendPostsRequest.onPostExecute(WSAdapter.java:104)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Posts.java

```
public class Posts extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView postsSect;
    Button postsDoneBtn;
    WSAdapter.SendPostsRequest PostsHelper;
    StringBuilder postsBuffer = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        PostsDetails postDetailsHelper = new PostsDetails();
        //postDetailsHelper.ListPosts();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);

        postsDoneBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PostsDoneButton);
        postsSect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PostsSection);

        PostsDetails postDetailsHelper = new PostsDetails();

        postDetailsHelper.callPostDetails("http://192.168.0.18:8000/api/");
        //postDetailsHelper.ListPosts();

        postsDoneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Posts.this, MainActivity.class));

            }
        });
    }

    public class PostsDetails {
        //String post_title, post_content;
        ArrayList<Integer> post_id = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> post_title = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> post_content = new ArrayList<String>();

        boolean isPDCalled;



        // sets if Post details are called

        // checks if postsDetails functions are called for AsyncTask
        boolean getIsPDCalled(){
            return isPDCalled;
        }

        // calls the execute for AsyncTask
        private void callPostDetails(String theurl){
            PostsHelper = new WSAdapter().new SendPostsRequest();
            // executes AsyncTask
            PostsHelper.execute(theurl);
        }

        // sets values for the posts arrays
        public void setPost(int p_id, String p_title, String p_content) {
            this.post_id.add(p_id);
            this.post_title.add(p_title);
            this.post_content.add(p_content);
        }

        public ArrayList<Integer> getPostID() {
            return this.post_id;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getPostTitle() {
            return this.post_title;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getPostContent() {
            return this.post_content;
        }

        // Lists the posts from the database
        public void ListPosts() {
            /////////// add functionality if a post was deleted and was clicked

            int lastFrJSONArray = getPostID().size() - 1;

            postsSect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PostsSection);

            // outputs the id of the very first post, something to put to the textview
            postsSect.setText("id: " + getPostID().get(0) + "\n");
            for (int i = lastFrJSONArray; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                // appending the titles and contents of the current post
                postsSect.append("title: " + getPostTitle().get(i) + "\n");
                postsSect.append("content: " + getPostContent().get(i) + "\n");

                // if this is the last post, then don't need to append id for the next post.
                if (i != 0) {
                    postsSect.append("id: " + getPostID().get(i) + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WSAdapter.java

```
public class WSAdapter {

    /*@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }*/

    public class SendPostsRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        TextView postsSect;
        // Add a pre-execute thing
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        private WeakReference<Activity> mPostReference;

        /*public SendPostsRequest(Activity activity){
            mPostReference = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
        }*/

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

            }catch( Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /*finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }*/

            return result.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            // expecting a response code fro my server upon receiving the POST data
            Log.e("TAG", result);

            Posts.PostsDetails postsHelper = new Posts().new PostsDetails();

            // For posts
            try {
                JSONArray pJObjArray = new JSONArray(result);

                // algorithm for parsing the JSONArray from the Django REST API
                for (int i = 0; i < pJObjArray.length(); i++) {
                    // puts the current iterated JSON object from the array to another temporary object
                    JSONObject pJObj_data = pJObjArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // inputs necesarry elements to the ListPosts function
                    postsHelper.setPost(pJObj_data.getInt("id"), pJObj_data.getString("post_title"), pJObj_data.getString("post_content"));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                //Toast.makeText(JSonActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Json","Exception = "+e.toString());
            }

            postsHelper.ListPosts();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "Please ignore the fact that I placed my AsyncTask to a different activity." – That's what's causing the current issue. `WSAdapter` is not actually being used as an `Activity`, and it should not extend any `Activity` class. You're instantiating that class yourself, and it calls `findViewById()`, which is throwing the Exception because it's not acting as an `Activity`, as it's not been instantiated and initialized by the system. I'm not sure why you've made `SendPostsRequest` an inner class there, but it doesn't seem like it needs to be. Why don't you have it as a top-level class?

Comment: As mentioned by @MikeM. in the above comment **kindly restructure your code properly**.  As you have mentioned in code `WSAdapter extends AppCompatActivity` and no view is not associated to it so `postsSect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PostsSection);` will result in **null only**.

Comment: without setContentView, How can you use **findViewById** ?

Comment: Oh ok. I have tried to pass activity context method prior to this, but removed it since it may cause memory leak if the activity was closed before `asyncTask` was done. But I will work on your answers now! Thank you so much! I didn't realize that AsyncTasks being in an activity can be fatal.

Comment: Ok so the WSAdapter is not an activity now, but I am still getting the same error. My AsyncTask is getting called tho and processing.

Answer (score -1):

First of all restructure your code. And for setting text make those fields static which you want to use and then set their values in the onPostExecute of AsyncTask or else you can return the jsonstring as it is to your activity and then parse it there and set values for better readability.